# Is there a way to display the geometry of the Subd. surf. modifier together with the original geometry?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, wireframe

Is there a way to display the geometry of the Subdivision surface modifier together with the original geometry in solid view in edit mode? Lets assume that the image below is a screenshot from that view. It is pretty usefull when modeling with the subdivision surface modifier, so that you can always see how the geometry flow is going. Is something like that possible to achieve (I couldn't make the grid floor in the image, but assume it is there.)?

[image]

Something like that is possible in 3DS Max.

In 3DS Max - 
[image]

Comment: Nope, AFAIK this is the closest you can get: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/76063. IMO seeing the subserf wires would get pretty busy..

Comment: @Vladimir What about just toggling applying the modifier to the editing cage when it edit mode? It should show the smoothed model and the actual mesh.

Comment: Edit mode in solid shading only draws the editable mesh. In wireframe shading you can also see the subdivided edges but it isn't very clear. In object mode you can enable wire drawing for the object and toggle Optimal Display in the subsurf modifier to show/hide the extra geometry as an on/off comparison but the same colour is always used for drawing edges.

Comment: I knew that, however thanks for the information. Sometimes it is handy when the two wire-frames are visible, for example - if I have to extrude some polygons after applying the subsurf modifier, I struggle knowing when there is enough detail from the modifier and it saves time toggling "on" and "off" the "wire" display in Object mode.